# Magento Configurable Product Attribute

Tags: magento

I would like to add a parameter to each option of a configurable product
For example- I want to create pillows in 3 sizes - S, M, L
but each size of pillow uses some z yards of fabric which varies for each size.

The following image displays it better. Any ideas on how I should proceed? *I am fairly new to Magento development. Is this something that can be achieved out of the box or needs to be coded?

[image: So each size has a textbox for entering yards associated with each size]

Comment: hey currently i am having the same issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431481/how-to-add-options-to-particular-attribute-options-in-magento   can you please tell me what exactly you did.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a new attribute (yard)

- Scope: Global
- Input Type: Dropdown
- Use To Create Configurable Product: Yes
- Insert some labels / options

2) Assign this new Attribute to the Default Attribute Set

3) Create a new Configurable Product using both size and yard attributes

Comment: I need to be able to create an option corresponding to each option Small, and Large. The solution you gave allows me to create a product which has size options and yardage option. I want to associate certain yards to option Small of a config product and different yards to the Large option.