# How to add Options to particular attribute options in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

`I want to add options against each attribute options in magento. Dont know how this is possible.`

Suppose i have an attribute `size` which has `3 options` like `small` , `medium` , `large`

`Now i want to add options against each options.`

like for `small` i want to add `22`,`24`,`26`

for `medium` i want to add `28`,`30`

for `large` i want to add `32`,`34`

please check the image below

[image]

here fabric has lot of options like house `linen cotton , brush linen cotton, soft wool,` etc

here each options has lot of fabric options.

Comment: You might have more luck over on http://magento.stackexchange.com/, although it sounds like you just want a product that's configurable by two attributes, and then only add simple products for the combinations you want for sale.

Comment: got what i want ..thanks for your valuable feedback..previously i thought it cant be managed from magento admin..must have to do some coding stuff hence i post it here. Anyway its good that it can be managed from admin panel. AND thank you SIR.

Comment: Sir @AlanStorm its exactly like that what you told but in that case simple product is not taking its price rather taking configurable products price to the cart..i created a demo product for this...if you have little time please check this  http://magento-kingshuk.rhcloud.com/index.php/t-shirt/fabric-config.html  .Dont know why this is happening.

Comment: You could add multiple options like `small - 22`, `small - 24`, `small - 26`, `medium - 28`, etc. On the frontend, you could add code that groups options by the part before the `-`. The backend does not really need "sub options" to do what you want the frontend to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a cultural/language thing, but it's unclear what you're asking.  Based on the comments above though — it sounds like you're confused about configurable product pricing.   The way configurable product pricing works is the *base* product price come from the configurable price, and then each attribute value can have a price modifier.

In a stock system there's no way to have a configured product price come from the resulting simple product. There's a few extensions out there to do it for you, but I'm not sure which ones work with the latest version of Magento, so google/[the Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) is your friend there.

Implementing this yourself is more complicated than a simple Stack Exchange answer can provide — you'll need to understand the relationships between the product model, product type instance, and promotion rules to full implement something like this.

Good luck.